# "data : JSON.stringify(e_data)" set data value to null

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf

```
var e_Data={"userId":userId, "componentId":componentId, "eventId":eventId};
$.support.cors = true; 
$.ajax
({
    type:'POST',
    data:JSON.stringify(e_Data),
    url:'http://localhost:11502/EventStreamService.svc/SentEventData', 
    contentType:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(data){alert("data:"+data);}, //data:null ????why
    error:function(){alert("not responding");} 
});
```

WCF service interface

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke( Method = "POST", 
                BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, 
                RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
                UriTemplate = "/SentEventData/")]
    void SentEventData(int userId, string componentId, string eventId);
```

WCF service class

```
    public void SentEventData(int userId, string componentId, string eventId)
   {
           evnd = new eventData();
           evnd.UserId = userId;
           evnd.ComponentId =componentId;
           evnd.EventId = eventId;
       try
       {
           evnd = this.ConnectToDatabase(evnd);
           this.ConnectToEvent(evnd);

       }
       catch (Exception e) { throw e; }
   }
```

I have created WCF service that receives data from a website made by HTML. The ajax request is connecting with service but data is always set to null. I tried to test the content of my data with alert("data:" + data) and the result is (data: null). the communication between my service and JQuery ajax request is working but there is no further data process because of the null value. Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Your ajax to the web service is only sending one parameter which is the json string. On the service side, it would be received as a single string, not multiple. You need to convert that string back to the individual values.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, How can I change JSON string into individual values?

Comment: I changed my data to an object and removed the JSON.stringify but still getting a null value for data in ajax. Any ideas why is it set to null again? Do I need to change something in my service as well?